# UITableViewCell subview disappears when cell is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm implementing a color-chooser table view where the user can select amongst, say, 10 colors (depends on the product). The user can also select other options (like hard drive capacity, ...).

All color options are inside their own tableview section.

I want to display a little square on the left of the textLabel showing the actual color.

Right now I'm adding a simple square UIView, give it the correct background color, like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:RMProductAttributesCellID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:RMProductAttributesCellID] autorelease];
        cell.indentationWidth = 44 - 8;

        UIView *colorThumb = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 28, 28)] autorelease];
        colorThumb.tag = RMProductAttributesCellColorThumbTag;
        colorThumb.hidden = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:colorThumb];
    }

    RMProductAttribute *attr = (RMProductAttribute *)[_product.attributes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    RMProductAttributeValue *value = (RMProductAttributeValue *)[attr.values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = value.name;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIView *colorThumb = [cell viewWithTag:RMProductAttributesCellColorThumbTag];
    colorThumb.hidden = !attr.isColor;
    cell.indentationLevel = (attr.isColor ? 1 : 0);

    if (attr.isColor) {
        colorThumb.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
        colorThumb.backgroundColor = value.color;
    }

    [self updateCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

This displays fine without problems.

My only problem is that when I select a "color" row, during the fade-to-blue selection animation, my custom UIView (colorThumb) is hidden. It gets visible again just after the selection/deselection animation ended, but this produces an ugly artifact.

What should I do to correct this? Don't I insert the subview at the right place?

(There's nothing special in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I just change the cell's accessory to a checkbox or nothing, and deselect the current indexPath).

Comment: What's upadteCell all about ?

Comment: updateCell does some minor tweaks like setting the checkmark or not, choosing text color depending on availability, ... but no real change related to the cell itself or the colorThumb.

Comment: the accepted answer does not provide the solution, see my answer below for solution

Answer (score 225, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` changes the background color of all sub views when cell is selected or highlighted ,You can Solve this problem by overriding Tableview cell's `setSelected:animated` and `setHighlighted:animated` and resetting view background color.

**In Objective C :**

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   UIColor *color = self.yourView.backgroundColor;        
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if (selected){
        self.yourView.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}

-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated{
    UIColor *color = self.yourView.backgroundColor;        
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    if (highlighted){
        self.yourView.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

**In Swift 3.1 :**

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let color = yourView.backgroundColor         
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        yourView.backgroundColor = color
    }
}

override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    let color = yourView.backgroundColor
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

    if highlighted {
        yourView.backgroundColor = color
    }
}
```

Comment: Do we need the `if (highlighted)` and `if (selected)` conditions? I think it will work if we don't have those conditions.

Comment: @RishabhTayal it is basically to avoid overriding the variable with the same value

Comment: Mind that when you change the background color while the item is selected, the old (wrong) color might be restored when the item becomes unselected. If that can happen, remove the if (highlighted) and if (selected) conditions.

Comment: This approach cancels the animation, so it has no sense. Better to set cell selection style to .none.

Answer (score 121):

It's because the table view cell automatically changes the background color of all views inside the content view for the highlighted state. You may consider subclassing `UIView` to draw your color or using `UIImageView` with a custom 1x1 px stretched image.

Comment: Dumb me. Of course that was it, subviews have to be transparent so that the selection animation can occur properly. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can re-set the background color overriding `setHighlighted:animated:` and `setSelected:animated:`

Comment: Somehow resetting the background color did not work for me (running on iOS 8.1). Instead solved this by subclassing my view and overriding setBackgroundColor as [super setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]].

Answer (score 44):

Found a pretty elegant solution instead of messing with the tableViewCell selection/highlighting methods. You can create a subclass of UIView that ignores setting its background color to clear color.

Swift 3/4:

```
class NeverClearView: UIView {
    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if backgroundColor != nil && backgroundColor!.cgColor.alpha == 0 {
                backgroundColor = oldValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Swift 2:

```
class NeverClearView: UIView {
    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if CGColorGetAlpha(backgroundColor!.CGColor) != 0 {
                backgroundColor = oldValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obj-C version:

```
@interface NeverClearView : UIView

@end

@implementation NeverClearView

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor {
    if (CGColorGetAlpha(backgroundColor.CGColor) != 0) {
        [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: This is lovely. Easily the best solution if you have some re-usable view like a "badge" or "tag" that should just never have a clear background. ::rant:: what a confounding solution @UIKit, setting all child views to transparent when you do a cell selection. At least limit to child views that are the full height or width of the cell, or ones at N depth.

Comment: @SimplGy The depth of highlighting would be indeed a sweet option, but hey - this is UIKit, I have seen things SO much worse than this =)

Comment: Worked for me after I changed the if to CGColorGetAlpha(backgroundColor!.CGColor) == 0 as it wasn't equal to clearColor

Comment: Great solution!  No longer necessary with the iOS 13 SDK.

Answer (score 10):

For **Swift 2.2** this works

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

and reason is explained by @[Andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746201/1371853)

> It's because table view cell automatically changes background color of
>   all views inside content view for highlighted state.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to manage the problem is to fill the view with core-graphics gradient, like:

```
CAGradientLayer* gr = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gr.frame = mySubview.frame;
gr.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.5] CGColor]
                     ,(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.5] CGColor]
                     , nil];

gr.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1],nil];

[mySubview.layer insertSublayer:gr atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying this exact code and it isn't having any effect at all for me.  My subview is a UILabel added as a subview of cell.contentView, and testing under iOS 6.0.1, in case that matters.

Comment: What do you apply the code above to? And have you tried to add the label simply to the cell view?

Comment: This is the perfect solution in my opinion. Drawing to the layer addresses the issue perfectly, while keeping full flexibility. I don't like the solution of using a UIImageView, because then it's harder to adjust the gradient or the color (you'd have to make a new image each time), and subclassing UIView just for this seems overkill.

Comment: @Lyida, I am not really Swift-developer. (I even more C#-one). But from what I've seen, that's not rather language-specific thing, however, mostly Cocoa/iOS Frameworks logic one. So, the idea is just to place almost transparent CAGradientLayer into your view to obtain the result requested.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by
[Yatheesha B L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024072/yatheesha-b-l)'s
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27717607/1984384)
I created a UITableViewCell category/extension that allows you to turn on and off this transparency "feature".

**Swift**

```
let cell = <Initialize Cell>
cell.keepSubviewBackground = true  // Turn  transparency "feature" off
cell.keepSubviewBackground = false // Leave transparency "feature" on
```

**Objective-C**

```
UITableViewCell* cell = <Initialize Cell>
cell.keepSubviewBackground = YES;  // Turn  transparency "feature" off
cell.keepSubviewBackground = NO;   // Leave transparency "feature" on
```

KeepBackgroundCell is CocoaPods compatible. You can find it [on GitHub](https://github.com/timbodeit/KeepBackgroundCell)

Answer (score 7):

You can `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`, 
then set the backgroundColor at `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by [Yatheesha B L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27717607/2666902)'s answer.

If you call super.setSelected(selected, animated:animated), **it will clear all background color you set**. So, we **will not call** super method.

**In Swift :**

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {    
    if(selected)  {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red 
    } else {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}

override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if(highlighted) {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red 
    } else {
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. +1
Overriding the ishiglighted variable and sethighlighted method are different things. the correct answer is to override the method.

Answer (score 4):

For may case, This is the Septs to avoid getting the gray color for all items in the cell (in case you are using custom table view cell):

1. Set the selectionStyle to .none  `selectionStyle = .none`
2. Override this method.

   > func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool)
3. Call the super, to get the benefit of super setup.

   > super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
4. Do what ever highlighting logic you want.

   ```
   override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
         super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
         // Your Highlighting Logic goes here...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

UITableViewCell changes the backgroundColor of all subviews on selection for some reason.

This might help:

[DVColorLockView](https://github.com/DylanVann/DVColorLockView)

Use something like that to stop UITableView from changing your view color during selection.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the view instead of setting background colour

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {

    var fillColor:UIColor!

    convenience init(fillColor:UIColor!) {
        self.init()
        self.fillColor = fillColor
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if let fillColor = fillColor {
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillColor.CGColor);
            CGContextFillRect (context, self.bounds);

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**SIMPLEST** solution without bugs with animation (as in the top rated answer) and without subclassing and drawing - set layer's border color instead of backgroundColor and set very big border width.

```
colorThumb.layer.cornerRadius = 6
colorThumb.layer.borderWidth = colorThumb.frame.width
colorThumb.layer.borderColor = value.color
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code:

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{     
[super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
//Set your View's Color here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to override `setSelected` as well as `setHighlighted`

```
override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    someView.backgroundColor = .myColour()
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {

    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    someView.backgroundColor = .myColour()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Pavel Gurov's answer, but more flexible in that it allows any color to be permanent.

```
class PermanentBackgroundColorView: UIView {
    var permanentBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            backgroundColor = permanentBackgroundColor
        }
    }

    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if backgroundColor != permanentBackgroundColor {
                backgroundColor = permanentBackgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to keep the default selection behavior except for one cell subview that I wanted to ignore the automatic background color change. But I also needed to be able to change the background color at other times.

The solution I came up with was to subclass `UIView` so it ignores setting the background color normally and add a separate function to bypass the protection.

**Swift 4**

```
class MyLockableColorView: UIView {
    func backgroundColorOverride(_ color: UIColor?) {
            super.backgroundColor = color
    }

    override var backgroundColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            return
        }
        get {
            return super.backgroundColor
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution,use contentView to show selectionColor,it's work perfectly

```
#import "BaseCell.h"

@interface BaseCell ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color_normal;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL needShowSelection;
@end


@implementation BaseCell
@synthesize color_customSelection;
@synthesize color_normal;
@synthesize needShowSelection;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setup];
}

- (void)setup
{
    //save normal contentView.backgroundColor
    self.color_normal = self.backgroundColor;
    if (self.color_normal == nil) {
        self.color_normal = [UIColor colorWithRGBHex:0xfafafa];
    }
    self.color_customSelection = [UIColor colorWithRGBHex:0xF1F1F1];
    self.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if (self.selectionStyle == UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone) {
        needShowSelection = NO;
    }
    else {
        //cancel the default selection
        needShowSelection = YES;
        self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
}

/*
 solution is here
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (needShowSelection) {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor = color_customSelection;
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    if (needShowSelection) {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor = color_normal;
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if (needShowSelection) {
        UIColor *color  = selected ? color_customSelection:color_normal;
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place this code in your subclass of `UITableViewCell`

**Swift 3 syntax**

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if(selected) {
        lockerSmall.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 233/255, green: 106/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}


override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)

    if(highlighted) {
        lockerSmall.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 233/255, green: 106/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding another solution if you're using storyboards. Create a subclass of `UIView` that does not allow the `backgroundColor` to be set after it is initially set.

```
@interface ConstBackgroundColorView : UIView

@end

@implementation ConstBackgroundColorView

- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor {
    if (nil == self.backgroundColor) {
        [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

If the background solution mentioned above isn't fixing your problem, your issue may lie in your `datasource` for your tableView.

For me, I was creating an instance of a DataSource object (called `BoxDataSource`) to handle the delegate and dataSource tableView methods, as so:

```
//In cellForRowAtIndexPath, when setting up cell
let dataSource = BoxDataSource(delegate: self)
cell.tableView.dataSource = dataSource
return cell
```

This was causing the dataSource to be deallocated whenever the cell was tapped, and thus all the contents disappeared.  The reason being, is ARC deallocating/garbage collecting nature.

To fix this, I had to go into the custom cell, add a datasource variable:

```
//CustomCell.swift
var dataSource: BoxDataSource?
```

Then, you need to set the dataSource to the cell's dataSource `var` you just created in cellForRow, so this isnt deallocated with ARC.

```
cell.statusDataSource = BoxAssigneeStatusDataSource(delegate: self)
cell.detailsTableView.dataSource = cell.statusDataSource
return cell
```

Hope that helps.