# Titanium TableViewRow removes background color of subview when selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, titanium

I have a custom TableViewRow with a subview for an image. The imageView is inside a container so I can display the image as a square. The container has a white background and the image may not fill the container view. I removed the image from the container to explain the problem better. Please see the images below.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, when the bottom row is selected the background of the white square disappears. In my case, when the image is inside the container, the white color that fills the square is removed and I have a square border with a smaller image inside it.

Has anyone dealt with this before?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behavior for any table -- it changes the background color of all the subviews so it can show the selection highlight.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745919/uitableviewcell-subview-disappears-when-cell-is-selected) for more details and work-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion here is to handle the selectionHighlighting yourself so you can manage how the views are rendered.

Once a row is selected, create you own method to set the background color of the individual views to give the visual experience you want. Remember to set the tableView so there is not highlighting on selection