# Custom UITableViewCell does not show content when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My simple custom `UITableViewCell` subclass does not show its content when selected. When I tap one of the cells, the green view disappears and I only see the cell's red background color. When I select another cell, the content of the previously selected one appear again. Any ideas?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString*)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        UIView* someView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
        someView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        [self.contentView addSubview:someView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

I registered this with in my view controller's `viewDidLoad':

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
```

And here is how I create them:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745919/uitableviewcell-subview-disappears-when-cell-is-selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background of your cell should be set in the `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` properties, not added as a subview of `contentView`. Only the content (text, images, etc.) should be in `contentView`.