# Circle View is gone when press UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, layer

In UITableViewCell's contentView, I have put a `UIView` and set its layer cornerRadius to half of its height to make it a circle.And set its color to red.
When I run it and press the `UITableViewCell`,the red circle becomes transparent.

Before press the cell.

[image]

After press the cell.

[image]

Where goes wrong,I think it is something to do with `cornerRadius`.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because UITableviewCell change the view background color when selected.

You need to subclass the UITableviewCell,and change the backgroundcolor back

Screenshot

[image]

Code

```
class CustomCell:UITableViewCell{
override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
    let view = self.viewWithTag(10) //The tag of this view is 10
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    let view = self.viewWithTag(10)
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523138/subview-of-uitableviewcell-disappear-when-uitableviewcell-is-highlighted-anyway/31523271#31523271) :

> UITableViewCell changes the background color of all sub views when
>   cell is selected or highlighted.

I have adapted my previous answer for your question

You have three options :

1. If you don't want any selection style

   ```
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   ```
2. Subclass `UITableViewCell` and overriding Tableview cell's `setSelected:animated` and/or `setHighlighted:animated` like [Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31577052/1836115) answered
3. Add the circle as a layer

   ```
   CALayer* layer = [CALayer layer];
   layer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 30);
   layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
   layer.cornerRadius = 20/2.0f;
   [cell.contentView.layer  addSublayer:layer];
   ```