# cell selection in multi choice mode of tableview is overlapping the content of view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I dont know why my cell content is overlapping on cell selection in multi selection mode. Please help. Screenshot is attached in the link.
!(https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6PMl-B4JKuCLWhaMEUwVGlvMFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you elaborate exactly what you mean by overlapping? They look fine on the screenshot, dont' they?

Comment: maybe just add a separator to make it look better (the tableview has a separator property)

Comment: Basically the problem is blue box is not appearing on selection. only labels are appearing.. same thing has been happened for orange color dot also.

Comment: oh alright. You need to hide/show that using a state for your cell, or use two different custom cells

Comment: Can you please explain how to hide and show or point me to some sample code if possible

Comment: Got the solution thanks every one. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745919/uitableviewcell-subview-disappears-when-cell-is-selected)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by using two different customized `UITableViewCell` and two identifiers.

`UITableView` object maintains a queue (or list) of the currently reusable cells, each with its own reuse identifier, and makes them available to the delegate in the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`: method.

Answer (score 0):

'overlapping' you mean by gray selection color then you can set table selection style to None.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

If your cell is reusing unwanted style, then implement `-(void)prepareForReuse` in your custom cell class. And reset your cell in prepareForReuse() function. so it will reset the image view before reuse the cell.

Comment: I have tried changing style to None. Now i cannot see selected check color. Its looks like white color. Please suggest how to update it.