# Swift TableView Prevent Button color change on selection

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift3

I am having a hard time preventing color change on my background color for my `IBAction` button when I select a row in my `tableView`. The background of my button is set to green, but when I tap the table view cell, it becomes gray. I have tried to change the color through different functions (tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` etc..). Any ideas on how I would prevent the background of the button to change?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This answer might lead you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6746201/340508

Comment: how about changing the tableview cell selection style to `None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced same problem with button `backgroundColor` in `TableView` and solved it this way.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. The code is working if I just tap a table view cell. However, if I was to hold the touch, the background color of the button turns gray. Do you have a soultion for this as well? By the way, sorry for the late response.

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable color change on selection entirely, change the selectionStyle attribute in your custom cell:

```
selectionStyle = .none
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - FYI apply this to the cell, not the tableView

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the code Nirav provided me above:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

However, I noticed that the button background color continued to turn gray when I tapped the row, and held the 'tap' without releasing. I solved this by adding the following code as well:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.exploreButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

}
```