# Label is not visible after selecting table row

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have an table row with 2 labels and 1 image view. Only one label and the image view are visible when I select the row.

When I view the table:

[image]

It looks perfectly right, but this is what I see when I select an row, the red dot is gone (but why?):

[image]

I have this at my storyBoard:

[image]
[image]

Does someone know how to fix this issue? Because I want to 'see' the red dot always, even when selecting. I have tried to change the zPosition to 9999, but that didn't help. What is the issue here, as the other label and image view are normal.

Edit:

The cell code:

```
import UIKit

class DeviceViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var deviceImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deviceDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var onlineStatus: UILabel!
}
```

The didSelect code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DeviceViewCell
   }
}
```

The cellForRow code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:DeviceViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! DeviceViewCell

    cell.deviceDescription.text = self.roomObject.getDeviceAtIndex(index: indexPath.row).getName()
    cell.deviceImage.image = self.roomObject.getDeviceAtIndex(index: indexPath.row).getImage()


    return cell
}
```

I know what happens, the red dot is an label without text, but it has an red background color. The background color disappears when you select the cell. Does someone know how to prevent this behavior?

Solved the issue: [UITableViewCell subview disappears when cell is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745919/uitableviewcell-subview-disappears-when-cell-is-selected)

Comment: Can you post the code of your controller and/or cell

Comment: You don't need to change Z position at all. Just show me a code which you have written in cellForRow and didSelectAtIndexPath

Comment: @anilkukdeja I have added the code.

Comment: @da1lbi3 : I can see the half completed code. Where is cellReuseIdentifier defined in your code? I can not see that. Please post a full code.

Comment: pls add this  "cell.selectionStyle = .None" and make height and width contraint  of network lbl to some fixed value(30,30) and then try.

Comment: @V12 That works, but the cell reacts very slow when I click it and the background is gone when you click it.

Comment: for background you need to use some custom view. but selectionStyle will not effect any performance maybe some other code is reacts slow..

Comment: The code is fast, it becomes slow if I add "cell.selectionStyle = .None" at the cellForRowAt method.

Comment: put the code at DeviceViewCell and try

Comment: @da1lbi3 pls check my answer at below may that resolve your cell reacts (slow) perfromance.

Answer (score -1):

state : .Normal  and state:Selected

see func  tableview (rowDidSelect ...)